# WPF: Binding the same image to multiple rows in a DataGrid (improving performace)

Tags: c#, wpf, image, binding, datagrid

I have a DataGrid with several bindings for each column. One column is for an image. I already found, that the following way works for binding images in wpf DataGrid.

```
<DataGridTemplateColumn Header="" Width="SizeToCells" IsReadOnly="True">
    <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Image Width="16" Height="16" Source="{Binding imagePathStatus, IsAsync=True}"/>
        </DataTemplate>
    </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
</DataGridTemplateColumn>
```

```
public class DataGridObject 
{
    public String imagePathStatus { get; set; }

    ...
}
```

This is a status and there are 3 types. The same type means the same picture. I had a lot of problems referring to performance of the UI. Especially when my background task invokes the UI after setting the status of one column. But also initializing the GridView (without any other thread besides the UI) takes a long time. Deactivating the image column solves the problem.

I'm searching now for hours and have tried a lot of things.

I've already put the images into resources and uses them via

```cs
this.imagePathIcon = "pack://application:,,,/Etlxxx;component/GraphicUserInterface/Images/image.jpg";
```

I declare the binding to async, so at least the UI will not freeze.

To my mind, the problem is that every row loads the image, even if they uses the same picture. Probably because I just bound the path. According to my knowledge there is no way of binding directly an image.

Everything works fine. But I can see that every Image is loaded separately. I'm really confused.

The pictures are really small (16x16), but still slows down the whole application.

Is there a way to bind the same image to multiple rows in a DataGrid. Ideally, the application has to load an image one time and shows it immediately in every row where it belongs to.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: "According to my knowledge there is no way of binding directly an image". That is not true. Declare a property of type `ImageSource`, e.g. `public ImageSource StatusImage { get; set; }`, and assign a BitmapImage, like `StatusImage = new BitmapImage(new Uri("pack://application:,,,/Etlxxx;component/GraphicUserInterface/Images/image.jpg"))`. Then bind the Image control's `Source` property, like `<Image Source="{Binding StatusImage}"/>`

Comment: That solved the problem. Thank you very much. Is it possibly to flag your comment as solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can of course directly bind to an image, instead of an image path url.

Just declare a property of type `ImageSource`, e.g.

```
public class DataGridObject 
{
    public ImageSource StatusImage { get; set; }
    ...
}
```

and bind to it like this:

```
<Image Source="{Binding StatusImage}"/>
```

Now you can assign a `BitmapImage` (or some other ImageSource-derived object), e.g. directly like this:

```
item.StatusImage = new BitmapImage(new Uri(
    "pack://application:,,,/Etlxxx;component/GraphicUserInte‌​rface/Images/image.j‌​pg"));
```

or from a previously created BitmapSource:

```
item.StatusImage = somePreloadedBitmapImage;
```

or as well from XAML resources:

```
item.StatusImage = (ImageSource)Resources["imageResourceKey"];
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. Knowing, that i can even bind an image opens up whole new possibilities.

Answer (score 1):

Use a static resource.

```
<Window.Resources>
    <BitmapImage x:Key="MyImageSource" UriSource="./images/error.png" />
</Window.Resources>
<Grid>
    <DataGrid Name="dataGrid" >
        <DataGrid.Columns>
            <DataGridTemplateColumn>
                <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <Image Width="16" Height="16" Source="{StaticResource MyImageSource}"/>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
            </DataGridTemplateColumn>
        </DataGrid.Columns> 
    </DataGrid>
</Grid>
```

Assuming the image is in "images" directory.

Comment: Thanks for the participation. I will try this. But, the status will change during the runtime. Is there a way of chaning the reference to a static ressource of one row? Ideally via Binding...